# C# and PostgreSQL Single Row Mode

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

When streaming large volumes of data out of PostgreSQL into C#, using Npgsql, does the command default to Single Row Mode or will it extract the entire result set before returning? I can find no mention of Single Row Mode in the Npgsql documentation, and nothing in the source code to suggest that it is optional one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Npgsql sends the SQL query you give it, PostgreSQL will immediately send back all the rows. If you pass `CommandBehavior.SingleRow` (or `SingleResult`) to `NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader`, Npgsql will simply not return those rows to the user; it will consume them internally, but they are still sent from the server. In other words, if you expect these options to reduce the network bandwidth used, that won't work; your only way to do that is to limit the resultset in the SQL itself, via a LIMIT clause. This is in general a better idea anyway.

See https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/410 for a bit more detail on why we didn't implement something more aggressive.

Comment: When you say "immediately send back all the rows", do you mean that as soon as it finds the first row, it will send that back, then when it finds the second, that will get sent, etc., or do you mean that it will calculate the entire result and then send them back to the client?

Comment: PostgreSQL will in general stream the rows back - it will not buffet all does and only then send them back. In fact, if the client doesn't consume does fast enough, PG may block from further processing of the query (TCP zero window) until more rows are consumed.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the default in Npgsql is to get a cursor for the result set that will fetch the number of rows you are currently processing, basically, when invoking `reader.Read()` you get a row from the server to the driver client. There might be some buffering taking place, but streaming the result is the norm.